# Print ZPL labels with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, zpl

Im using this example to print labels:
https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-Zebra-ZPL-commands-from-Javascript/
everything its working fine,except that if i want to print more than 1 label per click it dosent allow me to do it, for example if Im using a for or while cycle to print,but everytime the for moves on the alert that Says Print now appears everytime
this is how that last part looks like in my code
n = 0;

```
while (n < 2) {
          n ++;

        var cmds =  "^XA";

        cmds += "^FO480,21^ARN,1,90^FD/^FS";  
        cmds += "^FO62,36^AUN,90,100^FDEL ZAPATON^FS";
        cmds += "^FO0,135^ARN,60,14^FDDama 4^FS";
        cmds += "^FO0,200^ARN,60,40^FD^FS";
        cmds += "^BY2,2,100";
        cmds += "^FO10,270^BC^FDE0430601926027^FS";
        cmds += "^FO410,273^AUN,100,75^FD$350.50^FS";
        cmds += "^FO50,20^GB530,120,6,B,0"

        cmds += "^XZ";
        cpj.printerCommands = cmds;


        //Enviar impresion a Zebraimpresora
        cpj.sendToClient()
```

;

Comment: double it up....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print multiple copies just double it up.

```js
var zplStr =
`^XA
^FO480,21^ARN,1,90^FD/^FS
^FO62,36^AUN,90,100^FDEL ZAPATON^FS
^FO0,135^ARN,60,14^FDDama 4^FS
^FO0,200^ARN,60,40^FD^FS
^BY2,2,100
^FO10,270^BC^FDE0430601926027^FS
^FO410,273^AUN,100,75^FD$350.50^FS
^FO50,20^GB530,120,6,B,0
^XZ`;

const numOfCopies = 2;
var cmds = new Array(numOfCopies).fill(zplStr).join("\n");
console.log(cmds)
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine, i can now print it multiple times without asking me with that messagebox of printing everytime, but can i have let say an array fill with data like this ["TENIS", "VARIOS", "VARIOS"] inside the zpl code and print it multipletimes without that printing message? before i tried doing that in a for loop and for the zpl code i did concatenation inside the zpl code and it was being filled with that array data. it worked fine, the problem was that i keep geting that print message everytime the for did a loop

Answer (score 0):

**Add Button in HTML Page**

```
<button onclick="printSticker()">Print Sticker</button>
```

**Add Link in HTML Page**

```
<script src="https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/zebra_com/software/en/application/javascript/BrowserPrint-2.1.18.min.js"></script>
```

**Make a Function to print stickers**

```
<script>
    // Initialize the Browser Print SDK
    BrowserPrint.init();
    function printStickers() {
        var numStickers = 5; // Number of stickers to print

        var zplCode = "^XA" +
                      "^FO100,100" +
                      "^A0N,50,50" +
                      "^FDHello, World!" +
                      "^FS" +
                      "^XZ";

        BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice("printer", function (printer) {
            if (printer && printer.connection) {
                if (printer.connection === "usb" || printer.connection === "network") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < numStickers; i++) {
                        printer.send(zplCode, function () {
                            console.log("Sticker printed successfully.");
                        }, function (error) {
                            console.error("Failed to print sticker:", error);
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("The selected printer is not a Zebra printer.");
                }
            } else {
                console.error("No printer available.");
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("Error retrieving default printer:", error);
        });
    }

</script>
```